# Advice on the type of JOIN I should use in this scenario using MySQL Database

Tags: mysql

I have 3 sections as follows;

1. TIER I
2. TIER II
3. TIER III

*Each having tables as below*

1. Objectives
2. Performance Measures which references Objectives
3. Performance Actual which references Performance Measure

The Objectives of Tier II references those of Tier I & those of Tier III references those of Tier II.

**My requirement**
I want to get Tier II Performance from Tier III performance, and also get Tier I performance as from Tier II performance.

**What I have Tried**

```
SELECT
  d_o.ObjectiveName,
  ia.Q1 AS 'Q1Actual',
  ia.Q2 AS 'Q2Actual',
  ia.Q3 AS 'Q3Actual',
  ia.Q4 AS 'Q4Actual',
  i_o.ObjectiveName AS 'Individual Objective',
  fy.FY AS 'FY',
  AVG(ia.Q1),
  dpm.DeptMeasureId,
  dpm.Q1,
  ia.*
FROM
  individual_appraisal ia
  LEFT JOIN individual_pm ipm on ia.MeasureId = ipm.MeasureId
  LEFT JOIN individual_objectives i_o ON ipm.IndObjectiveId = i_o.IndObjectiveId
  LEFT JOIN department_objectives d_o ON i_o.DeptObjectiveId = d_o.DeptObjectiveId
  LEFT JOIN department_pm dpm ON dpm.DeptObjectiveId = d_o.DeptObjectiveId
  LEFT JOIN tier_one_objectives t1_o ON d_o.TierOneObjectiveId = t1_o.TierOneObjectiveId
  LEFT JOIN financial_years fy ON t1_o.FYID = fy.FYID
WHERE
  i_o.StaffUser = 'staffuserName...'
GROUP BY
  dpm.DeptMeasureId
```

**Note**
I have attached a database diagram for the same to better understand the question.
[image: Database Diagram for the above Illustration.]

Your kind help is highly appreciated.

Comment: without knowing your result set that is wanted, you can only run the query adding a join after another and see if all rows that you need are there with all information

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I was surely running the Joins But I reached a point where the number rows increased which gave me the wrong results.

Comment: left joins takes all rows fr4om the left table and ties to add the rows from the right, so that you get more an more and ,more lke i said go join by join and check teh result and modify it. And also start with inner joins. it is a tidous approach but i don't know how else to go

Comment: Okay Thanks for your advise and time, Let me try doing that.

Comment: What do you mean by "type of Join"?  LEFT, INNER, CROSS, RIGHT, OUTER, etc?

Comment: "Section" and "Tier" are not database term; what do _you_ mean by them?

Comment: @RickJames I meant LEFT, INNER, CROSS, RIGHT, or OUTER. What could be suitable in that scenario. For Section & Tier, Sorry to use those terms but i thought it would be the best way to describe them. Tiers are different levels in the company. Tier 1 is at company level, Tier 2 is at department level and Tier 3 is at Individual level. Hope you now understand them. Waiting to hear from you. Thanks.

Comment: Don't put an array of things across columns -- Today there are up to 4 Questions; tomorrow there will be 5.  Don't have multiple tables with identical schema (pms).

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` and `JOIN` (aka `INNER JOIN`) are the primary candidates; @nbk explained the difference.  I don't grok the dataset enough to advise on which to use.